# The prefix "camunda" for element "camunda:connector" is not bound"

Tags: xml, eclipse, xml-namespaces, camunda

I am constantly getting the error:

> The prefix "camunda" for element "camunda:connector" is not bound.

Can someone tell me where the error is?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<serviceTask id="sendMail" name="Send Mail Task">
  <extensionElements>
    <camunda:connector>
      <camunda:connectorId>mail-send</camunda:connectorId>
      <!-- input / output mapping -->
    </camunda:connector>
  </extensionElements>
</serviceTask>
```

Comment: Where is this error appearing in the Eclipse UI?

Answer (score 3):

An XML namespace prefixed (`camunda` in this case) must be defined before use in order for XML to be [*namespace-well-formed*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

Change

```
<serviceTask id="sendMail" name="Send Mail Task">
```

to

```
<serviceTask id="sendMail" name="Send Mail Task"
             xmlns:camunda="NAMESPACE-URI">
```

Check Camunda documentation for the proper value of ***NAMESPACE-URI***.  It will likely look like one of the following:

- `http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/dmn`
- `http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn`